# 4+ multipoint BT headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm trying to find headphones for using with multiple equipment:

- TV
- tablet
- smartphone
- PC

All the *multi* point I can find handle only two devices.

Don't need to use multiple devices simultaneously, just use the same heaphones for multiple equipment without having to resync every time.

Comment: I think that you are mis-interpreting it.  These can connect to 2 devices simultaneously.  I had various ones over the years and they all pair with my 4 devices, even the ones that can only connect to one device at a time.

Comment: @RohitGupta I see I need to investigate a bit more. Right now every time I've paired mines to a new device they have unpaired themselves from the previous device. Maybe some models can do that. Pity is, manufacturer specifications rarely mention this.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using both the [*Bose QuietComfort 35 Wireless Headphones II*](https://support.bose.com/s/product/quietcomfort-35-wireless-headphones-ii/01t8c00000OydKkAAJ) and the [*QuietControl 30 Wireless Headphones*](https://support.bose.com/s/product/quietcontrol-30-wireless-headphones/01t8c00000OydL6AAJ). They can be connected to two devices simultaneously and store pairings for a total of eight devices. I.e., they will go through the list of eight devices in the order you were most recently connected, and connect to the first two that are available.

This works seamlessly as long as no more than two devices are within range and turned on. However, if, say, you use them in a hotel with your phone and your tablet, but the next day want to use them at home with your TV, but you also have your phone and tablet near you, then it will connect to the phone and tablet. You would have to go to one of those two devices and disconnect, then go into the settings of the TV to connect.

I also have the [*Bose QuietComfort Ultra Earbuds*](https://bose.com/p/earbuds/bose-quietcomfort-ultra-earbuds/QCUE-HEADPHONEIN.html) and before that the [*Bose QuietComfort Earbuds*](https://support.bose.com/s/product/bose-quietcomfort-earbuds/01t8c00000OydAIAAZ). These use an app called [*Bose Music*](https://bose.com/apps/bose-music) to manage them. In the app, you can select between all paired devices and tell the headphones which one to connect to.

I only personally have those two types of earbuds, but this presumably works the same for all current headphone products listed on the *Bose Music* page:

- [Bose Noise Cancelling Headphones 700](https://bose.com/p/headphones/bose-noise-cancelling-headphones-700/NC700-HEADPHONEARN.html)
- Bose Noise Cancelling Headphones 700 UC
- [Bose QuietComfort 45 Headphones](https://bose.com/p/bose-quietcomfort-45-headphones/QC45-HEADPHONEARN.html) (QuietComfort SE Headphones)
- [Bose QuietComfort Headphones](https://bose.com/p/headphones/quietcomfort-acoustic-noise-cancelling-headphones/QC-HEADPHONEARN-CYGRN-WW.html)
- [Bose QuietComfort Ultra Headphones](https://bose.com/p/headphones/bose-quietcomfort-ultra-headphones/QCUH-HEADPHONEARN.html)